# Elixir: eval'ing code in module context using Code.eval_quoted/3

Tags: metaprogramming, elixir

Given the following module:

```
defmodule Foo do

  def bar do
    IO.puts "I'm bar"
  end

  def eval(quoted_code) do
    Code.eval_quoted(quoted_code, [], __ENV__)
  end

end
```

Then the following code outputs `Foo` like expected:

```
# Outputs Foo
quote do
  IO.inspect __MODULE__
end |> Foo.eval
```

So why can't I call other functions in `Foo` from inside the quoted block?  For example, the following code gives me a `CompileError`:

```
# CompileError: undefined function bar/0
quote do
  bar
end |> Foo.eval
```

But the following code works:

```
# Outputs "I'm bar"
quote do
  import Foo
  bar
end |> Foo.eval
```

What exactly is the `import` statement doing?  Importing `Foo` into `Foo`?  That doesn't make sense to me.

From what I understand, `Foo.eval` is eval'ing the quoted code in the context of the `Foo` module.  But apparently thats wrong because I can't call other functions/macros from Foo without prefixing the calls with `Foo.`.  Furthermore, I don't understand how/why the `import` statement works:  Why do I need to `import Foo` when I'm already in the context of `Foo`?

What is going on here?  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Macros in Elixir are *hygienic*. This means, that they don't use callers context. Lets see an example from ["Metaprogramming Elixir" book](https://pragprog.com/book/cmelixir/metaprogramming-elixir)

```
number = 5
ast = quote do
  number * 10
end
Code.eval_quoted ast
** (CompileError) nofile:1: undefined function number/0
```

And second one:

```
number = 5
ast = quote do
  unquote(number) * 10 #the only change is unquote here
end
Code.eval_quoted ast
{50, []}
```

The idea is, that you can compute something at compile time and then (using macro) inject this value to the generated code. Macros can use the same variable names as your code and they *will not* conflict. If you know, what you are doing and really want to access variables from outer scope, you can use `var!`.

You are trying to do something opposite. You want to use something from your code in macro. This makes your macro not reusable.

Using import at the beginning looks like a good idea to show, that your macro depends on this particular module. It will work everywhere because of that line.

[EDIT to answer comment]:

When you pass `__ENV__` as the last argument, you don't import everything from the environment. Only those options, that ca be set, which are:

- `:file`
- `:line`
- `:aliases`
- `:requires`
- `:macros`

The problem is, that the environment has also other keys. The one, we would like to override is `context_modules`. This would allow calling things from inside the module. I am afraid it can't be done. This is a design decision.

In older versions of elixir (I checked 1.0), there was additional option `:delegate_locals_to`, but it is not present in 1.2.

Comment: I read (most of) Metaprogramming Elixir; it's how I got to this question... :)  So your example (I guess, the book's example) is using `Code.eval_quoted/3` without the 3rd argument (the one that I'm interested in), so if you put `IO.inspect __MODULE__` in the quoted block, you will get `nil`.  I'm passing `Foo.eval/0`'s `__ENV__` to `Code.eval_quoted/3`, so if I print `__MODULE__`, I get `Foo`.  That leads me to believe that my block is being eval'ed in the context of the `Foo` module and thus have access to all its functions... but it doesn't.

Comment: I edited my answer to explain, why you can't have access to all functions and why passing `__ENV__` doesn't set everything in new environment.